# Javascript url redirection not working in a multi-page sharepoint-hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, navigation, sharepoint-hosted-app

I wrote a sharepoint app that is almost entirely html/javascript/jquery. Bare minimum asp because that is not my expertise. It works great locally in all browsers when using pure html pages, but I'm getting an odd behavior when implanting the code into the aspx pages of a Sharepoint project and running it in Sharepoint after installation. Besides hyperlinks--which seem to work fine for some reason--any type of navigation I use causes the current page to reload rather than go to the intended destination. I have tried at least all of the following methods:

In a script with absolute and relative paths:

```
 1 window.location = url 
 2 window.location.href = url
 3 document.location = url 
 4 window.location.assign(url)
```

In the html:

```
 5 <button onclick="window.location = 'otherPage.aspx'">GO</button>
 6 <form action="otherPage.aspx">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
```

Why are my pages reloading instead of redirecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your button type to button. By default on the asp page your button is type submit
This was my post above

Comment: If you put a negatice vote on this answer please explain why. this is an issue I have run over many times when using an onclick function with a button element within a sharepoint form. <button type="button"></button> works with the onclick event

Comment: I didn't vote any answers down. But most of these options I used (eg window.location = url) I didn't even use a button for. Some were contained within change events and some in callbacks. All of them are causing the page to reload rather than redirect.

Comment: In your post it lookes like you were calling it from the onclick event.

Comment: I listed 6 different ways I tried calling it, but all that aside, I tried your method and it worked. Thank you. I wish I could upvote your answer but I lack the reputation to do so.

Comment: Do you have any advice for redirected within events? The first 4 examples I gave I tried in events and they only reloaded the page. I tried relative and absolute paths in all of them (I think).

Comment: Im sorry i am not understanding the full scope of what your asking. Please give an example of what is not working

Comment: I'll update my question to be clearer. Hold on.

Answer (score 0):

Set your button type to button. By default on the asp page your button is type=submit